# data.table way of doing this dcast

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I have a data.table which looks like this:

```
tbl
          lon lat hour ens       date value
       1: 254  31   12   0 1994010100     0
       2: 254  31   12   0 1994010200     0
       3: 254  31   12   0 1994010300     0
       4: 254  31   12   0 1994010400     0
       5: 254  31   12   0 1994010500     0
      ---                                  
40494956: 269  39   24  10 2007122700   200
40494957: 269  39   24  10 2007122800   130
40494958: 269  39   24  10 2007122900   240
40494959: 269  39   24  10 2007123000   230
40494960: 269  39   24  10 2007123100   150
```

and another one that looks like:

```
locs
    lon lat
 1: 260  33
 2: 261  33
 3: 262  33
 4: 263  33
 5: 260  34
 6: 261  34
```

And I am currently doing this with dcast to get it in the shape I need:

```
temp <- dcast(tbl[locs], date ~ lon + lat + hour, fun.aggregate=mean, value.var="value")
```

This does exactly what I want (even the column names!) but is very slow.  I would like a data.table way of doing it but after reading a few threads here, I still can't quite work it out.  My latest attempt is this:

```
temp <- tbl[locs, list(mean = mean(value), sd = sd(value)), by = list(date, lon, lat, hour)]
```

to collapse the `ens` variable (which works fine and NOTE that I am also calculating the sd as well), but I cannot reshape it.  My reshape attempt is:

```
temp[, as.list(setattr(list(mean,sd), 'names', list(lon, lat, hour))), by=list(date)]
Error in setattr(list(mean, sd), "names", list(lon, lat, hour)) : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]
```

Any help is of course greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: summarize data with `data.table` to get a small table, then `dcast` to reshape; it's possible to reshape directly but imo it's much more of a hassle for now (there does exist a FR to make it better though)

Comment: @eddi Thanks I'll try that. What is "FR"?

Comment: Feature request, I guess. [See here.](http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=browse&group_id=240&atid=978)

Comment: @mchangun, I'm guessing that now with `dcast.data.table` this problem has been addressed. If yes, please add an answer and accept it. If no, please edit your question with some reproducible sample data.